# C# mongodb field name duplication workaround

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following document.

```
{
   name: 'XYZ',
   SubscriptionPeriods" : [{
      "_id" : null,
      "PeriodCode" : "1M",
      "Fee" : "100"
    }, {
      "_id" : null,
      "PeriodCode" : "3M",
      "Fee" : "300"
    }]
}
```

An admin can update subscription periods; he can delete existing periods and/or add new periods in the same update. Initially I thought I could achieve this by doing PullAll(...) and  PushAll(...) on SubscriptionPeriods element in one Update(...). But it turned out that mongodb doesn't accept a field twice in an Update(...). I could have done PullAll(...) and PushAll(...) in 2 different Update(...)s. But I didn't take that approach because if someone tries to read SubscriptionPeriods between PullAll() and PushAll(), he will get an empty SubscriptionPeriods and that isn't acceptable.
So I came up with this; I created another element called SubscriptionPeriods1 in one update and renamed it to SubscriptionPeriod in another update. This looks to be working alight. But I am wondering if I am overlooking anything here ! I appreciate any comments that a MongoDB guru might have for me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, that's true, driver not accept two operations on same field. But, there is much simpler solution for your case.

`Update.PullAll("name", ..).PushAll("name", ..)` equals to `Set("name", bsonArray)`

So you need simply set new array instead of old one.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Actually, I did try Set(...) but it failed with an error saying 'Array can't be at the root of the bson document'. I used  something like Set("ArrayElementName",List<SomeType>.ToBsonDocument()). I think it is ToBsonDocument() that complained by saying 'array can't be at the root. I didn't realize that then and went ahead trying various other options before settling with the Rename(...). Nonetheless, BsonArray as the second argument to Set works !